# How do you create a NuGet package from a .NET Core MSBuild project in Visual Studio 2017 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, .net-core

Now that we have an official migration from `project.json` back to `.csproj`, how do you actually generate a NuGet package output?

I don't know if it's just me but I find it hard to understand the [official documentation pages](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/guides/create-net-standard-packages-vs2017). The only mention is about calling `msbuild` from the command line, but it's not really working for me, and besides I was more hoping that you could just specify this step directly in the `.csproj` file itself.

A complete example of how to do this using `.csproj` files would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Finally got the MSBuild to output the package by running it from the command line. The trick was fill in a `PropertyGroup` with all the package metadata as described in the doc pages. However, I still would much prefer to run pack as part of the normal build process.

**Update:** Found a much better resource for understanding the new `.csproj` format in the [.NET Blog page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/).

Comment: You should post them as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm packing a **.NET Core NuGet package** with **MSBuild** in **Visual Studio 2017 RC** using following steps:

1. Install **Visual Studio 2017** with **.NET Core and Docker (Preview)** component.
2. Create a following package information through `New -> Project -> C# -> .NET Core -> Console App (.NET Core)`.
3. Right-Click the **.NET Core project** to choose **Edit ProjectName.csproj** option to open the **.csproj** file in **Visual Studio 2017**.
4. Save a file under the **PropertyGroup** node with the following package information:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
       <PackageId>TestNetCorePackage</PackageId>
       <PackageVersion>1.0.0</PackageVersion>
       <Authors>Weiwei</Authors>
       <Description>Test .NET Core package</Description>            <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>false</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
       <PackageReleaseNotes>First release</PackageReleaseNotes>
       <Copyright>Copyright 2016 (c) Contoso Corporation. All rights reserved.</Copyright>
       <PackageTags>Net Core</PackageTags>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
5. Open **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 RC** and type `cd *your project file path*` command to navigate to your project file path.
6. Type `msbuild ProjectName.csproj /t:pack`, which is the command to pack your **.NET Core package**. It will generate in **bin\debug** folder in your project path.